# Display different buttons based on screen size

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design

I have the code for two html buttons, one for desktop, other for mobile.
I want to be able to display either one based on whether the page is being accessed from desktop or mobile.

How can I do that?

Mobile Button
Desktop Button

Comment: Research "responsive design"

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Comment: This is how boostrap does it using media queries: https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/jquery/layout/media-queries/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `@media` queries like so:

```css
button.first {
  display: none;
}

button.second {
  display: inline-block;
}

@media all and (max-width: 700px) {
  button.first {
    display: inline-block;
  }
  button.second {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<button class="first">First Button</button>
<button class="second">Second Button</button>
```

run the snippet and click on **full-page** to see the difference.

Answer (score 0):

have you try media query?

ex:

```
@mixin sm {
  @media screen and (min-width: 360px) {
    @content;
  }
}

@mixin md {
  @media screen and (min-width: 667px) {
    @content;
  }
}

@mixin lg {
  @media screen and (min-width: 834px) {
    @content;
  }
}

@mixin xlg {
  @media screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
    @content;
  }
}
```

then the way you use it like:

```
// medium size screen
@include md {
    .button_class {
      height: 10px;
  }

// large size screen
@include lg {
    .button_class {
      height: 100px;
  }
```

this is scss btw.

heres the equivalent in CSS:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 834px) {
   .button_class {
      height: 10px;
  }
}


@media screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
   .button_class {
      height: 100px;
  }
}
```

then try to resize your browser.